# Inheritance rules in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question about the basics of java.  I have the ***s*** attribute in each class.  The value of ***s*** gotten by the instance of the class is different when I use the accessor (getS()).  Is there a rule for this case?

The output of the main is :

```
x.s  = One
x.getS()  = Three
```

The classes definition  :

```
package com;

import com.Test1.A;
import com.Test1.B;

public class Test1 
{
    public static class A 
    {
        public static String s = "One";
        public int x = 10;

        public String getS() 
        {
            return this.s;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A 
    {
        public final String s = "Two";
        public String getS() 
        {
            return this.s;
        }
    }

    public static class C extends B 
    {
        public static int x = 1;
        public static String s = "Three";

        public String getS() 
        {
            return this.s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {

        A x = new C();
        System.out.println("x.s  = "+x.s);
        System.out.println("x.getS()  = "+x.getS());
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods are overridden, but fields are *hidden*, so they still exist when the reference type is of the parent class.

Comment: You've really made a mess for yourself here - you're mixing overloading, shadowing and statics. Take a step back! Go through a tutorial. Don't chuck the kitchen sink in - you'll never understand what's going on. And given the `String` "Three" doesn't even feature in your example; there's extra complexity you've elided. On top of the fact that you have at least two _different_ `x` variables in your example.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for saying that. The question in truth involves more than just inheritance.

Comment: I consider myself experienced Java developer and trainer, and I barely understand how this code will work :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : this code is given as part of one exam for the programming course.

Comment: @samara, could you please give a name of that exam?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, you need the whole exam? I can share it with you.

Answer (score 6):

The access of the field (`x.s`) is resolved through the compile-time type of `x` (which is `A`, so `A`'s `x` [`"One"]` is returned).

The access through the getter (`x.getS()`) is resolved through the runtime type of `x` (which is `C`, so `C`'s `x` [`"Three"`] is returned).

Some other examples:

- `((B) x).s` will return `"Two"`
- `((C) x).s` will return `"Three"`
- `((A) x).getS()` will return `"Three"`
- `((B) x).getS()` will return `"Three"`

(I leave the *why* as an exercise for the reader)

As an aside: the result does not change when

- `static` is removed from `String s = "One"` in `A`, or
- method `public String getS()` is removed from classes `B` and `C`, or
- both of the above

Please read [@Mike Nakis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57244784/4216641) as well.

One final remark on the code: the `import`-statements can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, rules for everything.

The expression `x.s` is problematic, because you are accessing a `static` field via an instance reference, and the compiler / IDE should have been issuing a warning for it. So, what this is telling me is that you are probably trying to compile java without important warnings enabled.  Don't do that, if this way you go, only pain you will find.  Read up on how to enable warnings on your compiler / IDE and enable as many of them as you possibly can.

The fix for the warning would be to replace `x.s` with `A.s`, and that would make clear exactly what is happening.

The `s` attribute that you are speaking of (more commonly referred to as 'field' in the java world) has been declared as static in some cases, but non-static in one case, and this does not look intentional.  Generally, `static` is to be used only in very special cases, don't use it if you do not have a very good reason for doing so.

Also, some fields are `final`, some aren't, and this does not look intentional, either.  You need to be very careful with these things.

Other than that, Turing85's answer basically covers it.

Comment: You might add the reason resolving the compiler warning would solve the question : namely, that it would result in `A.s` which is very explicit about where the value comes from.

Comment: This answer talks about everything, but the question itself.. in my humble opinion. final, static, not to use static, and not to refer to the static field from the instance reference.. but question is about something else.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword in front of your variables probably isn't what you intended and it pushes you into a weird corner of Java's semantics.

Here's what you probably intended:

```
public class Test1 {
  public static class A {
    public String s = "One";
    public int x = 10;

    public String getS() {
      return this.s;
    }
  }

  public static class B extends A {
    public B() {
      this.s = "Two";
    }

    public String getS() {
      return this.s;
    }
  }

  public static class C extends B {
    public C() {
      this.s = "Three";
    }

    public String getS() {
      return this.s;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A x = new C();
    System.out.println("x.s  = " + x.s);
    System.out.println("x.getS()  = " + x.getS());
  }
}
```

This prints

```
x.s  = Three
x.getS()  = Three
```

as you'd expect.

---

The main difference between what you wrote and what I wrote is that without the `static`, we're declaring that every `A` has an `s` field; with `static`, we're saying that the *concept* of `A`-ness has an associated `s` idea. This is useful in some limited circumstances (for instance, the Java `Integer` class has a static field called `MAX_VALUE` because the maximum possible integer is associated with the *concept* of integers; every integer doesn't have its own individual max value), but it's probably not the first concept you want to learn.

Comment: While your answer leads to the behavior OP expected from her code, it does not actually answer the question *why* OPs code behaves like it does.